# Issue with Unity3D Canvas PixelPerfect, LayoutGroup and ScrollRect

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

When the scene like below, the ScrollRect has no problem.

```
Canvas (Pixel Perfect toggle off)
--| ScrollRect ( ScrollRect + HorizontalLayoutGroup )
----| Content
----| Scrollbar
```

But when Pixel Perfect toggle of Canvas is on, the ScrollRect is not working.

```
Canvas (Pixel Perfect toggle on)
--| ScrollRect ( ScrollRect + HorizontalLayoutGroup )
----| Content
----| Scrollbar
```

And if remove the HorizontalLayoutGroup from ScrollRect, everything is back to normal.

```
Canvas (Pixel Perfect toggle on)
--| ScrollRect ( ScrollRect )
----| Content
----| Scrollbar
```

Hope someone can explain the reason behind it, thanks in advance.

I uploaded the test scene in [Unity3D forum](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/strange-behaviour-with-canvas-pixelperfect-layoutgroup-and-scrollrect.301843/), hope it can help you to understand the problem.

Comment: Do you by any chance use an OS X version? I had some bugs with UI system on OS X that were not reproduced on Windows.

Comment: It could be. I'll try on Windows to check.

Comment: I have same issue :(